# XSD to jaxb annotated classes gives cannot resolve xml element error

Tags: jaxb, xsd, jaxb2, xsd.exe, xsd-1.1

I have error free xsd. below is my xsd. i am just referring principal element. Jaxb converted classes gives the error: "Cannot resolve XML element declaration with namespace '' and name 'principal' in this context" on the @XmlRootElement(name = "principal"). Can somebody help here?

Here is my xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="authorization"><xs:complexType>           <xs:sequence><xs:element name="group" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element ref="principal" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" /></xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType></xs:element>  <xs:element name="principal" ><xs:complexType><xs:simpleContent><xs:extension base="xs:string"><xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="family" use="optional"/><xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"  use="optional"/>
</xs:extension></xs:simpleContent></xs:complexType></xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all your schema is wrong. I think you try to put something like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="authorization">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="group" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="principal" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                                minOccurs="1" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="principal">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="family" use="optional" />
                                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And with this XSD I have the same problem to you. If you change to this other XSD the problem will be resolved

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="authorization">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="group" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="principal" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                                minOccurs="1" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="principal">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="family" use="optional" />
                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Regards

Alex.